# Electron fs.writeFile - Problems saving the file more than once

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, fs

I am saving so json to a file like this:

first I `JSON.stringify` the data ... then...

```
fs.writeFile('myjson.json', contenthere, 'utf8', function(err) {
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
 console.log('File was saved');
});
```

This is actually saving the file and I get no errors but it won't load again or save again.

It's like I'm only allow to do it once but no errors.

Is there a better alternative to this so I can try it or any ideas on what the issue could be?

Comment: Maybe "contenthere" doesn't change ?

Comment: Also note that if you're using `require` to read the JSON file, require calls are cached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably more node issue, than electron. From the docs:

> Note that it is unsafe to use fs.writeFile multiple times on the same
>   file without waiting for the callback. For this scenario,
>   fs.createWriteStream is strongly recommended.

So, look into fs.createWriteStream method instead.

Link to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback).

Comment: Good answer. +1. But if you quote some docs, please also provide the link to it so anybody can follow it and have an in-depth read if they want